# How to convert [Any] to struct format in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting data in [Any] format and I want to convert data into the format mentioned below

```
struct Details {
    var image: UIImage? 
    var title: String?
    var subTitle: String?

}
```

Comment: You certainly get something more specific than `[Any]`

Comment: Just perform an optional casting: `array as? [Details]`. After that, unwrap the optional to check if the casting was successful.